# How contact details of people app works in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapterview

I've downloaded the contacts app from [**Github -platform_packages_apps_contacts**](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/) but when I open, it's full of errors. I've tried to fix the errors (but it only keep popping more and more) also, I tried to find if I needed any adapters, without success.

Here is the 'first' errors

[image: Errors]

I'm developing a similar activity and I retrieving data from a database, in a nutshell I need to know how the contactDetails activity works. I can't find a working example of that.

[image: Contact Screen]